# GridView Reorder on Windows 10

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app (WinRT) where I have a gridview where I can reorder images, and it's working fine.

The same app, on a phone running Windows 10 cannot reorder items.

The reorder mode is set correctly and the images are kind of floating just like on WP8.1 but when I drop items, nothing changes.

Is this a known bug  or is this a workaround to make it work ?

My code is as follow :

```
<GridView x:Name="GridView"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Margin="-3"
          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
          AllowDrop="True"
          CanReorderItems="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesReordered}">
```

and in code

```
private void EnableReorderMode()
{
    this.IsReordering = true;
    this.GridView.ReorderMode = ListViewReorderMode.Enabled;
}
```

**EDIT**

Just tried with simpler code (only xaml) :

```
<GridView AllowDrop="true"
              CanReorderItems="true"
              ReorderMode="Enabled">
        <GridViewItem>
            <Rectangle Width="80"
                       Height="80"
                       Fill="Red"
                       Margin="4" />
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Rectangle Width="80"
                       Height="80"
                       Fill="Yellow"
                       Margin="4" />
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Rectangle Width="80"
                       Height="80"
                       Fill="Green"
                       Margin="4" />
        </GridViewItem>
</GridView>
```

On a WP 8.1 app the reorder is working on a WP 8.1 but not on Windows 10 mobile.
On a W10 uwp, the reorder is working fine on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the same issue we are tracking on MSDN forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49a84f9f-69d7-4304-9cb7-ac44fd570252/w81-listview-canreorderitems-functionality-broken-in-windows-10-build-1511?forum=wpdevelop

Please keep monitoring that case, and we will update there about any progress. The same issue happens to ListView and GridView. By checking the internal status, the proposed fix will address both controls' issue from their base class. But I still cannot say when/how the fix will be available. If it is very urgent for you with big impact, please follow the instruction introduced by Prashant in that MSDN thread to contact MS support.

To workaround this issue, you need to handle the drag and drop by yourselves if above information cannot help you.

Comment: Thank you, I just dropped a comment on given thread. Hope the next build will fix this issue.